# How To Autoplay Embedded Videos in Android?

Tags: android

Can anyone help me on how to make my embedded video in android to autoplay when it loads.

example:
I have a videos button then when I click it, it will go directly to the video then autoplay it

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are two classes, MediaPlayer and VideoView. Maybe they can help you.

Comment: I used VideoView is it possible in it?

Comment: @John I think it will be work. But if you need more function, I think the 'MediaPlayer' will be better, and you need to read the AndroidDevelopers.

Answer (score -1):

Mediaplayer's start() can be called to automatically start a video.

Also see here too, though an audio file is used in the example: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Media/UsingServicetoplaymediafile.htm